# Shiny to Markdown - adressing objects with get function

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have built a shiny app and want to use the reactive functions in a markdown code. Download handler looks as follows, so no change in environment:

```
output$Report <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste('Report.pdf')
        },
        
        content = function(file) {
            src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
            
            # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
            # permission to the current working directory
            owd <- setwd(tempdir())
            on.exit(setwd(owd))
            file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
            
            library(rmarkdown)
                        
            out <- render('report.Rmd', pdf_document()) 
            file.rename(out, file)
        }
    )
```

If im adressing my objects directly by:

```
summary(Model_1())
```

It´s working fine. But if I want to put this in a function and getting the object with:

```
summary(get(paste0("Model_1()")))
```

Markdown cannot find the object. Since I have a highly dynamic shiny app, I want to get the summary by something like this:

```
function(i){
summary(get(paste0("Model_",i,"()")))
```

Also tried to pass the Model_1() with a params list to markdown and get it, but it didn´t work.
Don´t understand why get() has problems while direct adressing the object is working.
Can anyone explain the reason for that to me or has an alternative to get()?

Thanks!
best Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the *name* of the object you want to access to `get()`. The parentheses for accessing the value of a reactive are not part of that. Try `summary(get("Model_1")())` instead.

Comment: oh man, that´s too easy... Thank you so much. Didn´t thought about this!